# How to write to a tmp/temp directory in Windows Azure website

Tags: node.js, azure

How would I write to a tmp/temp directory in windows azure website?  I can write to a blob, but i'm using an NPM that requires me to give it file names so that it can directly write to those filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cloud Services (PaaS) or Virtual Machines (IaaS).

If PaaS, look at [Windows Azure Local Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx). This option gives you up to 250gb of disk space per core. Its a great location for temporary storage of information in a way that traditional apps will be familiar with. However, its not persistent so if you put anything there you need to make sure will be available if the VM instance gets repaved, then copy it to Blob storage. Also, this storage is specific to a given role instance. So if you have two instances of the same role, they each have their own local storage buckets.

Alternatively, you can use Azure Drive, which allows you to keep the information persisted, but still doesn't allow multiple parallel writes.

If IaaS, then you can just mount a data disk to the VM and write to it directly. Data disks are already persisted to blob storage so there's little risk of data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Just from my understanding and please correct me if anything wrong.

In Windows Azure Web Site, the content of your website will be stored in blob storage and mounted as a drive, which will be used for all instances your web site is using. And since it's in blob storage it's persistent. So if you need the local file system I think you can use the folders under your web site root path. But I don't think you can use the system `tmp` or `temp` folder.